# Postgres claiming to be out of space on drive with ample free space

Tags: database, postgresql, amazon-ec2, hard-drive

I'm relatively new to Postgres, but I'm getting a strange error and Googling hasn't turned up anything.

I've created two (relatively large) tables with about 200 million rows each. The first has 4 rows, the second 3 rows. They're each storing varchars in the each column.

I'm trying to create a third table by joining the two tables and selecting three of the resulting columns. The query is:

```
create table table_C as 
(select table_A.id as id, table_A.predicate, table_B.object as type 
from table_A join table_B on 
table_A.subject = table_B.subject);
```

The query runs for about 10 hours, then aborts saying

```
ERROR:  could not extend file "base/446695/504075.302": No space left on device
HINT:  Check free disk space.
```

I'm running this on an Amazon EC2 instance with 64GB of ram, and my database is stored on a volume with ~500GB free. I realize that the resulting table should be large, but the original two tables only take up less than 100GB so it would be bizarre if a table with two columns took up more than 5x more space. I've tried about 4 times, and have tried rebooting the instance.

I double checked that both the data directory and the pg_stats_tmp file are pointed to the correct volume. (Both the "data_dir" and "pg_stat_tmp" settings in postgres.conf).

Any thoughts? Is there some other temporary file that might be ballooning somewhere (the root volume has over 150GB free anyway)?

Comment: Try the same query with SELECT COUNT(*) , omitting all the other selected fields. Maybe you have an unwanted cartesian product somewhere.

Comment: I tried running the count query...it ran for about two days, then crashed the Postgres server =\

Comment: You mean: `SELECT COUNT(*) from table_A join table_B on 
table_A.subject = table_B.subject;` ? What are the definitions for A and B? how unique is the subject-column?

Comment: Yup that query. Table A is a bunch of RDF data, split into subj, pred, obj. Table B is two columns, a list of subjects from the first table and, and then a list of URI types. Table A is highly redundant, but B should be at least close to unique.

Answer (score 1):

If the subjects are duplicated, the join will repeat the rows combinations.

E.g.

Table1

1. Subject1
2. Subject1
3. Subject1
4. Subject2

Table2

1. Subject1
2. Subject1
3. Subject2
4. Subject2

Result will be 6 hours with Subject1 and 2 rows with Subject2 (8 rows in total)

In the most extreme case - subjects are totally identical - you'll get 200 mln * 200 mln rows.

I think it's the reason...

Comment: I'm pretty new to SQL, so I may be doing something foolish. The subject in the first table is not unique, but it is unique in the second table. What I'm trying to accomplish is to "append" a column to the first table by using the join to "look up" the key (the subject from the first table) in the second table (the "map") and return the "value", which then forms a new row that's like `first_table.subject second_table.value`. So if I understand how this works, I _italic_ not be getting a bloated Cartesian product since there are few if any repetitions in the second table.

Comment: You're right. If there are no repetitions in the 2'nd table, you'll get same count of rows as in the 1'st table (maybe minus some rows where subject is absent in the 2'nd table)